# I have installed a python library but dreampie won't import it

Tags: python-3.3

I have installed a python library in python3.3. When I run the interpreter in Dreampie, it can't find my newly-installed library, resulting in an error like:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a dreampie 1.2.1 bug.  To work around it, under Edit | Preferences | Shell, add the following line to the automatically-run code in the black box:

```
import site
site.main()
```

Comment: I also had to `import site` first

Comment: Or even better: `site.main()` instead of the second line.