# DreamPie doesn't load nltk library through import command

Tags: python

Importing some libraries doesn't work in [DreamPie](http://DreamPie.org).

For example `import nltk` results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
import nltk
ImportError: No module named 'nltk'
```

While the nltk has been installed and can be imported in the Python shell.
The DreamPie points to the same Python installation (3.4.1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have installed a python library but dreampie won't import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560723/i-have-installed-a-python-library-but-dreampie-wont-import-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Path doesn't include the path to site-packeges where nltk has been installed,
I added this path to the Path variable in Environment Variables settings in Windows and also modified it by the following code in python shell

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path\\python\\Lib\\site-packages")
```